# PyCharm says Expected }} after |default in a template

Tags: django, django-templates, pycharm

```
<div class="person_roles_div">
    <table>
        <thead></thead>

        <tbody>
            {% for position in person.positions %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ position.provider|default:"" }} {{ position.role }}</td>
                    <td>{{ position.facility|default:"" }}</td>
                    <td>{{ position.startdate|default:"" }}</td>
                    <td>{{ position.enddate|default:"" }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="remove_position_sk_{{ position.position_sk }}" class="position_remove_button">Remove</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

In the first four `td` tags that output a context variable and specify a default, PyCharm is highlighting the `:` and blank space right before and after each `""`

The hovertip message is `(( or {% expected`. The page runs fine.

Any idea what setting I should looking at?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

it's "Python template languages". See the screenshot:
[image]

Make sure it's set to "Django"

Comment: This help me a lot. For solving HTML inspection error, I search "pycharm inspect HTML error" but without findings. I think I lost the keyword `Django template`.

Comment: The same is true for IntelliJ with a django project